# I have a RBGW LED controller that is 4CH*4A but I need a controller that is 4CH*1.5A. Is there an easy way to make this 4CH*4A controller work?

Tags: led, pwm, controller

I have a RBGW LED controller that is 4CH*4A but I need a controller that is 4CH*1.5A.  Is there an easy way to make this 4CH*4A controller work? The controller is a PWM controller.

Could I simply add resistors (?) after the PWM? It's been a while since I've done an electronics project.

Comment: 4A is typically the capacity of the controller. With no other information, it will work - the load (LEDS) will only draw what they demand.

Comment: You have a constant-current or constant-voltage controller? The current really matters for constant-current circuits. But I think these colour LED systems are normally constant-voltage, so the current is just a maximum limit.